# Measurability of eigenelements $s \mapsto (\varphi_k(s), \lambda_k(s))$ of Laplace-Beltrami on $M_s$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, smooth-manifolds

For each $s \in [a,b]$, let $M_s$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with no boundary.

Under what conditions on $s \mapsto M_s$ do the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions $(\varphi_k(s), \lambda_k(s))_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of the Laplace-Beltrami operator $-\Delta_s$ associated to $M_s$ satisfy
$$s \mapsto \varphi_k(s)\text{ and }s \mapsto \lambda_k(s) \quad\text{are measurable (or continuous)?}$$

We obviously need some continuity of the $s \mapsto M_s$, but I'm not sure how to phrase it precisely. In my case $M_s$ are Euclidean hypersurfaces but I don't know if this affords much of a simplification to the problem.

There being no explicit representation of the eigenelements means that I am a bit stuck on this problem.

Comment: Just checking -- are you aware of work (including various pathologies) on the corresponding question for linear operators in general?  For example, in Kato, <em>Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators</em>.

Comment: @macbeth Sorry about late reply. No I am not aware of such things. Maybe worth checking out then.